# One Signal push notification launch URL error

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, swift2, onesignal

I am using one signal in my project. Their docs say

> OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c")

This code is from `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` in `Appdelagate`. In this case notification permission dialog showing shortly after launching. But I need to ask user permission another screen. When the application is in the background, the application opens when it is touched after the notification is disappeared, but the url closes with this error code:

> NSURLErrorDomain error -999.